# Use variables in docker-compose file image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I would like to pull and push my images to different repositories depending on the environment I am deploying them to.

My .env file obviously only works in a single environment and currently i have to use multiple docker-compose files to get around this.

Simply I would like to do something like this:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  my_service:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.somedockerfile
    image: ${docker_repo_host}:${docker_repo_port}/myimage:latest
```

Where I could pass in `docker_repo_host` and `docker_repo_port` dynamically when I am building. I am unsure if there is a way to do this neatly but any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Export the two variables

```
export docker_repo_host=your_host 
export docker_repo_port=your_port
```

Now run the docker-compose command

Comment: I would have to do this in every environment and that is what I am trying to avoid.